# Flow of logic in terms to fetch O auth 2 login and upload video to Youtube

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am banging my head against this since three days, I want to make an application which uploads videos to YouTube. For this I have implemented Google Plus sign in but I am confused as how to get the O-Auth token. Also I am unsure if this is the right way to go, or should I use any other mechanism to authenticate the user as Google provides so many, instead of one single well defined sign in mechanism.

So far my code is like:

```
public class YoutubeUpload extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    // Logcat tag
    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeUpload";

    Button upload;

    // Profile pic image size in pixels
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_upload);

        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

        // Button click listeners
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

        upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

        upload.setOnClickListener(onUpload); 



        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }


    private View.OnClickListener onUpload = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onUploadClick(v); 
        }
    };








    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);

    }

    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                txtName.setText(personName);
                txtEmail.setText(email);

                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    /**
     * Button on click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            // Signout button clicked
            signOutFromGplus();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            // Revoke access button clicked
            revokeGplusAccess();
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-out from google
     * */
    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Revoking access from google
     * */
    private void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    updateUI(false);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


        public void onUploadClick(View v) {

             Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             // In a real app, video would be captured from camera.
             File f = new File("/sdcard/test.mp4");
             uploadIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "video/*");
             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(uploadIntent, "Upload"));

             System.out.println("Exit");




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi user2822178 YouTube Data API supports the OAuth 2.0 protocol  for authorizing access to private user data. The list below explains some core OAuth 2.0 follow [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2)

for More

to Build a Complete Youtube App you have Two types

> 1. You need to Follow Youtube API
> 2. Direct Integration with your Google account

Note: If you are using 2nd way your app  should be for your own use other wise some one will misuse your Google ID.

IF this is not your problem,please Provide More Information of your code where you are missing..

Comment: Sorry but the 2.0 version is deprecated. I am trying to get an Auth token from a G+ sign in as I have implemented that already, but I dont have an idea of how to do that!

Comment: ok if you try with G+ Sign your app will be for your own use not others,because some one will misuse your Google ID..

Comment: Okay so do I have to scrape the G+ sign in and start afresh with the O auth 2 process?

Comment: yes if your app is public you need to Proceed with google api oauth process

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=de This is very very confusing